# How can I open my InDesign 7.2 document in 6.0 or convert it into PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I have a document that was saved as a InDesign 7.2.

Now I have version 6.0,  and I was wondering if there is any way to open it or convert it online to a 7.2 document and/or `PDF`.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign's backwards compatible format is [.IDML](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/save-indesign-files-previous-versions.html). Save out as that to open in older versions - I think it was introduced in CS5, and will open in CS4.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a free demo of the latest InDesign version from Adobe Creative Cloud and use it to convert your document. Unfortunately, there are no proven alternatives to InDesign for .indd files.